# Select all the dd tag until a new dl tag with Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm a Scrapy & Xpath beginner and I'm looking to parse a website with the following structure

```
<dl class="ismSummary ismHomeSummary">
        <dt>cat1</dt>
            <dd>value1</dd>
            <dd>value2</dd>
        <dt>cat2</dt>
            <dd>value1</dd>
            <dd>value2</dd>
</dl>
```

With Xpath I only want to get value1 & value2 ( the `dd`'s ) of cat1

This is what I have right now

```
//dt[text()="cat1"]/following-sibling::dd
```

The problem is it doesn't stop at cat2 and continue selecting value1 & value2 from cat2. :(

Comment: Syl, You were given a single XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted nodes. Instead, you chose to accept a more complex, unportable and less-maintainable solution that requires not only XPath evaluation but also additional host-language code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All nodes here are children of `dl`, so naturally all are siblings of the first `dt`, so when you use `following-sibling` you get them all.

Xpath was made with xml in mind, and in xml you probably would have the `dd` elements as children of `dt`, but unfortunately that's not the case here.

The easiest way woule be to just include all siblings of `dt` (not just the `dd`s) and iterate through the result set until a `dt` comes up. Using Xpath function to do do the same coule be possible, but is certainly more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
//dt[. = 'cat1']
     /following-sibling::dd
       [count(.| //dt[. = 'cat2']/preceding-sibling::dd)
       =
        count(//dt[. = 'cat2']/preceding-sibling::dd)
       ]
```

**Providing that `//dt[. = 'cat1']` and `//dt[. = 'cat2']` each select ony a single element, the above expression selects exactly the wanted two `dd` elements.**

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "//dt[. = 'cat1']
     /following-sibling::dd
       [count(.| //dt[. = 'cat2']/preceding-sibling::dd)
       =
        count(//dt[. = 'cat2']/preceding-sibling::dd)
       ]

  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (with the values of the last two `dd`s modified so we know for sure that the wanted elements are selected):

```
<dl class="ismSummary ismHomeSummary">
    <dt>cat1</dt>
    <dd>value1</dd>
    <dd>value2</dd>
    <dt>cat2</dt>
    <dd>value3</dd>
    <dd>value4</dd>
</dl>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the nodes it selects are copied to the output:**

```
<dd>value1</dd>
<dd>value2</dd>
```

**Explanation**:

Here we are using the *Kayessian method for node-set intersection* in XPath 1.0:

**The intersection of two node-sets: `$ns1` and `$ns2` is**:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

**In our case we substitute `$ns1` with**:

```
//dt[. = 'cat1']/following-sibling::dd
```

**and we substitute `$ns2` with**:

```
//dt[. = 'cat2']/preceding-sibling::dd
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dt[text()="cat1"]/following-sibling::dd[preceding-sibling::dt[1]/text()='cat1']
```